# pgAdmin Generate ERD stuck on load

Tags: pgadmin-4

When I open pgAdmin, right-click a database and press Generate ERD, it opens a new window and gets stuck on the "Fetching schema data..." screen.
Is this a bug that happens for everyone or does my pgAdmin not work for some reason?
Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It may not necessarily be stuck, but simply taking its time.

At least, this is what happened to me (see below). Couldn't find out thus far how to make it show whether progress is being made or it is genuinely stuck, but a lot may depend on the complexity of the database itself.

---

For the record, I'm a first-time pgAdmin 4 user on a Mac M1, and the only reason I installed it is because of its ERD tool. Inherited a legacy project at work with 55 tables, each with at least 5-10 columns, no documentation whatsoever. So after connecting to a PostgreSQL instance running on a cloud VM via SSH tunnel, I right-clicked on the database, and chose "ERD for Database" menu item.

After ca. 15-20 minutes, it eventually loaded the diagram, but it only displayed "Fetching schema data....." the whole time.

Comment: A few months have passed since I posted this question. 

I just opened up pgAdmin 4 on the web, tried generating an ERD for one of my old dbs, and it worked like a charm.

Guess there was a problem with Postgres themselves, but it is all better now.

Answer (score 1):

Well it may happen because of several reasons:

1. First check your database connection settings - make sure that DB that you are trying to generate ERD for is accessible and the connection settings are set properly.
2. Check the pgAdmin in compatibility mode as well - sometimes in Windows it works
3. Other reason which might be less important but you may also consider it in case of other ways don't work: try by disabling the antivirus and also try to post in pgAdmin community help